# Segmentation Fault printf C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The following code is giving me a Segmentation fault

```
void parseInput(char usrIn[])
{
char retCmd[MAX_INPUT];
retCmd[0] = usrIn[0];
printf('Debug: %c\n', retCmd[0]);
}
```

This is my first big project in C, but I think it's the printf giving me fault .. however I'm not sure...

Comment: What's the value of `MAX_INPUT`, what are you passing to the function when calling it? It's hard to help you if your question is so vague.

Comment: Sorry, it's #define MAX_INPUT 64

Comment: You need to use a string literal, not a character constant, not sure how it even compiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Your original line:***

```
printf('Debug: %c\n', retCmd[0]);
```

---

***How it should be:***

```
printf("Debug: %c\n", retCmd[0]);
```

---

**Notice the change from single-quotes to double-quotes**

Comment: Thanks I will make this correct answer when the time runs out ... I would have never noticed that ... even though I should of..

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that the array is not zero-length. If it is, then the first element is empty and you will get a segfault when you try to access a non-existent element in the array. You can get the array length using `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`, or by using `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, and checking argc for the number of elements in the argv array.